# Java passing parameter to child process

Tags: java, process, runtime, runtime.exec

I am using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)` to start a PostgreSQL server. When start the server using the above command, I see a new process is getting created to start the process apart from `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` process.

```
john 14330  0.0  0.0 128244  2568 pts/88   S+   19:35   0:00 pg_ctl -D /u/john/postgre_test/data/ start -w
john 14334  9.5  0.0 124592  3736 pts/88   S+   19:35   0:00 /usr/bin/postgres -D /u/john/postgre_test/data
```

As you can see, first one is created because of exec() method and new second one is also created. Now since the server requires SSL private key password which has to be passed. If I pass it using

```
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(process.getOutputStream());
    ps.println(keyPassword);
    ps.flush();
```

I guess it is not setting to intended process so the server is not getting started. How can I pass the parameter to the process that was created recently? Or is there any other way to make it work?

Comment: so process is the object returned by the Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) ?

Comment: When you create the Process, there are probably command line parameters that you build onto the end of the String.    How would you write a 'one liner' for starting the server from a console prompt?

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is not passing a parameter, but writting into the process STDIN.

To pass parameters to a process, use [`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[] command)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29); the first position of the array is the command and the rest are the parameters.

Comment: The String "cmd" in Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) is a string array. String cmd[] = {"/usr/bin/pg_ctl", "-D", "/u/john/postgre_test/data/", "restart", "-w"};

Comment: What would be the command line that you would use in shell? That would help in clarifying the question.

Comment: pg_ctl -D ~/postgre_test/data/ restart -w - This is the command  I use to execute in command line.